# Lower volume when converting between .wav bitrates

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, naudio

I'm creating a program to help me out with some bulk-wav conversion (since I *often* have to convert files to specific sample rates). And what I always have been before when converting is to lower the volume to 85% of the normal (to avoid clipping). But now with NAudio I can't seem to understand how I should do this.

This is the method I'm using to convert the wav files.

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFiles[i]))
{
    using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader))
    {
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(newPath, conversionStream);
    }
}
```

How would I be able to set the volume?

Answer (score 1):

After some more exploring and looking around I found the [`NAudio.Wave.VolumeWaveProvider16`](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveProviders/VolumeWaveProvider16.cs) class, which does exactly what I want!